# How to display data from MONGODB to ANGULAR 5's html

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular5

I've been stuck here since yesterday. 
I have an API that retrieves data from mongodb (mlab.com)

```
var helpers = require('../config/helper.js');
var UserModel = require('../model/UserModel.js');

module.exports = function (server){

server.get("/", function (req, res, next) { 
        UserModel.find({}, function (err, users) {
            helpers.success(res, next, users);
        });    
});
}
```

This is the UserModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId; 


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    email_add: String,
    champ_type: String
}); 


var UserModel = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

My app.js

```
//packages
const restify = require('restify');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const restifyValidator = require('restify-validator');
const corsMiddleWare = require('restify-cors-middleware');


//local
var setupController = require('./controller/setupController.js');
var userController = require('./controller/userController.js');
var config = require('./config/dbConfig.js');

//init packages
const server = restify.createServer();
mongoose.connect(config.getMongoConnection());

setupController(server, restify, restifyValidator, corsMiddleWare);
userController(server);

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

ALL OF THE ABOVE IS WORKING WHEN I TRIED IT ON POSTMAN

[SCREENSHOT OF THE POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkIaq.png)

NOW LET'S GO TO MY ANGULAR 5 PROJECT

First, I generate a component(retrieve.component) using the CLI.

Second, I created a service[logging.service.ts], code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';// If you need external data
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';// If you need to call some API from the cloud
import { Request } from "@angular/http";

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { LogModel } from '../model/log.model';


@Injectable()
export class LoggingService {
  private ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  //getPosts() {
  //let params = new HttpParams().set('userId', '1');
  //this.posts = this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL /*, { params }*/);
  //}

  addComments(): Observable<LogModel[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option


    return this.http
      .get(this.ROOT_URL, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: any) =>Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server error"));
  }

  test() {
    //console.log("Hello!");
    const subject = new Subject();

    subject.subscribe({
      next: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      }
    });

    subject.next("Hello!");
    subject.next("Free!");
  }
}
```

Third, I created a model (log.model.ts), code:

```
export interface LogModel {
  lname: String;
  fname: String;
  email_add: String;
  champ_type: String;
}
```

Fourth, I configured my component (retrieve.component.ts), code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


import { LoggingService } from "../service/logging.service";
import { LogModel } from "../model/log.model";


@Component({
  selector: "app-retrieve",
  templateUrl: "./retrieve.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./retrieve.component.css"]
})
export class RetrieveComponent implements OnInit {
  //posts: Observable<any>;
  private results: LogModel[];
  private model: any;

  constructor(private _loggingservice: LoggingService) {}

  getAllusers() {
    this.model = this._loggingservice.addComments().subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      //this.results = Array.of(this.results);
    }
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('getBooks completed')
  );
    console.log(this.model);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._loggingservice.test();
  }
}
```

Fifth, configured my retrieve.component.html, code:

```
<p>
  retrieve works!
</p>

<button (click)="getAllusers()">Get Posts</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of results?.data">
  <p>Output: {{ item }}</p>
</div>
```

Sixth, configured my app.module.ts, code:

```
// This typescript file is called a module. It is a group of components bundled together.
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NgForm,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  FormsModule
} from "@angular/forms"; // for you to enable ngModel in HTMLs
//import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Before you can use a component, you'll need to declare it here
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './iprofile/profile.component';
import { ProfileService } from './iprofile/profile.service';
import { LoggingService } from './service/logging.service';
import { RetrieveComponent } from './retrieve/retrieve.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // Then here.
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    RetrieveComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // for you to enable ngModel in HTMLs
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ProfileService, LoggingService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Lastly, I implement it on the main html (app.component.html), code:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ name }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<h3>Facker</h3>
<hr>

<app-servers></app-servers>
<app-profile></app-profile>
<app-retrieve></app-retrieve>


<!--

<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>

 <ul>
  <li>

    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul> -->
```

[Here's the screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nqx8.png) PS. When I press "get Posts" button it shows "[Object object]"

So, thank you for reading all the stuff. I just want to know what goes wrong? I just want to display to my Angular 5 project what the postman displayed. I'm trying to google simple tutorials but it doesn't work. By the way, restify and corsmiddleware are my default packages, what I mean is you can suggest but I think that won't solve the problem.

Comment: It already worked. I'll just my solution here. 
I changed `this.http.get` 

code with this 

**return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/`, options)**

and I modified my retrieve.component.html with

`<button (click)="getAllusers()">Get Posts</button>
<div *ngFor="let result of results?.data; let i=index">
    <a style="color: black"> {{result?.fname}}</a>
</div>`

I think the ngFor syntax is my problem. 
the "?" is meaning your accessing the inner part of the array, sorry for being stupid enough to post a problem that I can solve -_- 
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have got this piece of code:

```
getAllusers() {
this.model = this._loggingservice.addComments().subscribe(data => {
  this.results = data;
  //this.results = Array.of(this.results);
```

`data` here is represented as a *json*, but you want it to be an *object*. Try to `JSON.parse()` your data like this:

```
getAllusers() {
this.model = this._loggingservice.addComments().subscribe(data => {
  this.results = JSON.parse(data);
```

If this isn't working, try to `JSON.stringify()` your `response` instead of `response.json` here:

```
return this.http
  .get(this.ROOT_URL, options)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

Here I give working example of getting response from API and parsing it into custom object:

```
public loadPage() {
this.http
  .get(environment.API_URL + "search/" + this.query + "/" + pageToLoad.toString())
  .map((data) => JSON.stringify(data))
  .subscribe((data) => {
    const page: Product[] = JSON.parse(data);
    this.showedProducts = this.showedProducts.concat(page);
  });
}
```